# Not able to change the background of the scene in cocos2dx android

Tags: c++, android, cocos2d-x

I have started Game Development using Cocos2d-x. And started with HelloWorld sample game. I am able to run this sample game. But when I try to change the Background Color, I am getting error in

```
 HelloWorldScene.h
    The type 'HelloWorld' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'cocos2d::CCRGBAProtocol::setOpacity' 

Changes:
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::CCLayerColor
```

and also in

```
 **HelloWorldScene.cpp**

    Invalid arguments '
    Candidates are:
    bool initWithColor(const cocos2d::_ccColor4B &, ?, ?)
    bool initWithColor(const cocos2d::_ccColor4B &)
    '
   **Changes:**
   CC_BREAK_IF(!CCLayerColor::initWithColor(ccc4(255,255,255,255)));
```

I am new for Cocos2d-x and also for C++. Is there any thing left to include or what?

Comment: Did the whole cocos2d-x compilation went well? This should work. Which cocos2d-x version do you use? How did you create this project?

Comment: Ya, whole cocos2d-x goes well only when I use

class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::CCLayer

as I change it to 

class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::CCLayerColor

it shows above errors in both the classes

Answer (score -1):

in my case my problem was solved after writing this for background color change to white
  glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);